# Apache Camel is failing silently if there is any missing dependecies

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm using the DSL to build an async queue processor.

The code of the route looks something like this:

```
from("seda://exportListQueue")
                .setProperty("originalRequest", simple("${body}"))
                .setHeader("CamelRedis.Key", Builder.simple("Something"))
                .setHeader("CamelRedis.Value", Builder.simple("Some Json"))
                .to("spring-redis://the_host:the_port?serializer=#stringSerializer")                .setBody(exchangeProperty("originalRequest").convertTo(MyClass::class.java))
                .process(queueProcessor)
                .to("http4:some_url)
```

(This is kotlin btw, but it really does not matter)

Of course, I've changed the names because I can't disclosure the non-generic parts. My problem is that when I try to run the application, Camel stops immediately. The logs are something like this:

```
[INFO ] [2019-04-01 18:57:46,089] [] [] [o.a.c.l.i.Jdk14Logger->log:87] | Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in exceptionHandlerController
[INFO ] [2019-04-01 18:57:46,995] [] [] [o.a.c.l.i.Jdk14Logger->log:87] | Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
[INFO ] [2019-04-01 18:57:46,998] [] [] [o.a.c.l.i.Jdk14Logger->log:87] | Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
[INFO ] [2019-04-01 18:57:47,010] [] [] [o.a.c.l.i.Jdk14Logger->log:87] | Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
[INFO ] [2019-04-01 18:57:47,079] [] [] [o.a.c.s.b.RoutesCollector->loadXmlRoutes:279] | Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
[INFO ] [2019-04-01 18:57:47,080] [] [] [o.a.c.s.b.RoutesCollector->loadXmlRests:296] | Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
[INFO ] [2019-04-01 18:57:47,084] [] [] [o.a.c.i.DefaultCamelContext->start:3138] | Apache Camel 2.23.1 (CamelContext: RED) is starting
[INFO ] [2019-04-01 18:57:47,085] [] [] [o.a.c.i.DefaultCamelContext->doStartCamel:3312] | MDC logging is enabled on CamelContext: RED
[INFO ] [2019-04-01 18:57:47,085] [] [] [o.a.c.m.ManagedManagementStrategy->doStart:205] | JMX is enabled
[INFO ] [2019-04-01 18:57:47,249] [] [] [o.a.c.i.DefaultCamelContext->doStop:3496] | Apache Camel 2.23.1 (CamelContext: RED) is shutting down
[INFO ] [2019-04-01 18:57:47,256] [] [] [o.a.c.i.DefaultCamelContext->doStop:3596] | Apache Camel 2.23.1 (CamelContext: RED) uptime 0.171 seconds
[INFO ] [2019-04-01 18:57:47,256] [] [] [o.a.c.i.DefaultCamelContext->doStop:3597] | Apache Camel 2.23.1 (CamelContext: RED) is shutdown in 0.007 seconds
```

Logging with trace level, we get to the root of the problem:

```
[TRACE] [2019-04-01 19:01:06,419] [] [] [o.a.c.u.EventHelper->doNotifyEvent:1091] | Notifier: org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector$2@7dd847a2 is not enabled for the event: Failed to start Camel: RED due to Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[spring-redis://the_port:the_host?serializer=#stringSerializer] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[seda://exporQueue]] -> [SetProperty... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: spring-redis://the_host:the_port?serializer=%23stringSerializer due to: No component found with scheme: spring-redis
```

In the end, it was just a missing dependency. But my question is, isn't Camel supposed to give me an exception or at least a warning telling why it is shutting down in a more friendly way.

Am I missing something or is it really a non beautiful Camel behavior that deserves a ticket?

--- EDIT ---

This is the dependencies related to the startup

```
dependencies {

    // spring web
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")

    // cache
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache")

    // spring retry
    compile("org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.1.5.RELEASE")

    // monitoring
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging")

    // camel
    compile('org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:2.23.1')
    compile('org.apache.camel:camel-spring-redis:2.23.1')
    compile('org.apache.camel:camel-http4:2.23.1')

    // eaio uuid
    compile("com.eaio.uuid:uuid:3.2")

    // apache
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7")
    compile("commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11")
    compile("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3")

}
```

Comment: I get a big ol' stack trace if I try to run your code without those dependencies.  What version of Camel are you running?

Comment: Yeah I also get Camel swearing and spitting at me when I don't include the right dependencies.Could be a version issue.

Comment: Makoto which version of camel are you using?

Comment: It also depends how you start Camel if you do this manually you can also end up swallowing exceptions etc. Put a sample project on github that reproduces the issue if you want others to help / look at it.